# Using service layer functions in a java project without spring

Tags: java, azure-functions, singleton, service-layer

I am writing an azure function in java. To use a good modular pattern I created a service layer which has abstract interface classes and an impl layer that implements the service layer.

However, I am not using `Spring-framework` so I can't use `@Autowired` to create a singleton instance of the service layer in the runner file. How can I use my service layer functions in my runner class (or other places in my project)?

**Service Layer**

```java
public interface TimeTriggeredService {

  String getLogs(String token, String url,final ExecutionContext context);
}
```

**Impl Layer**

```java
public class TimeTriggeredServiceImpl implements TimeTriggeredService {

  public String getLogs(String token, String url,final ExecutionContext context) {
    // Some logic
  }
}
```

**Runner Class**

```java
public class TimeTriggeredFunction {

  @FunctionName("TimeTriggeredFunction")
  public void run(@TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "0 */1 * * * *") String timerInfo,
      final ExecutionContext context) {
    
    String timeAuditLogs = TimeTriggeredService.getLogs(token, URL ,context);  // unsure what should replace this line or what should be done before this. 
  }
}
```

**Note** : This is NOT a spring project.

Comment: @Inject will do the DI for you.

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dependency Injection for Java is not supported yet.** Check out GitHub issue around the same: [#324](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/324).

> For now, you can use Spring Framework to use Azure Function for HTTP
> requests only (not the bindings.
>
> [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/hello-spring-function-azure/hello-spring-function-azure/) is a sample of how to use it.

*If you do not want to use Spring framework, you will have to create a global instance in the class and use it.*